# How to allocate a large memory in C

Tags: c, linux, gcc, memory

I'm trying to write a program that can obtain a 1GB memory from the system by `malloc(1024*1024*1024)`.

After I got the start address of the memory, In my limited understanding, if I want to initialize it, just using `memset()` to achieve. But the truth is there will trigger a **segfault** after a while.

And I tried using gdb to find where cause it, finally found if I do some operate of memory **more than 128 MB** will lead to this fault.

Is there has any rule that limits program just can access memory less than 128 MB? Or I used the wrong way to allocate and initialize it?

If there is a need for additional information, please tell me.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

[Platform]

- Linux 4.10.1 with gcc 5.4.0
- Build program with `gcc test.c -o test`
- CPU: Intel i7-6700
- RAM: 16GB

[Code]

```
    size_t mem_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    ...
    void *based = malloc(mem_size);  //mem_size = 1024^3
    int stage = 65536;
    int initialized = 0;
    if (based) {
            printf("Allocated %zu Bytes from %lx to %lx\n", mem_size, based, based + mem_size);
    } else {
            printf("Error in allocation.\n");
            return 1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    while (initialized < mem_size) {  //initialize it in batches
            printf("%6d %lx-%lx\n", n++, based+initialized, based+initialized+stage);
            memset(based + initialized, '$', stage);
            initialized += stage;
    }
```

[Result]

```
  Allocated 1073741824 Bytes from 7f74c9e66010 to 7f76c9e66010
  ...
  2045 7f7509ce6010-7f7509d66010
  2046 7f7509d66010-7f7509de6010
  2047 7f7509de6010-7f7509e66010
  2048 7f7509e66010-7f7509ee6010  //2048*65536(B)=128(MB)
  Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Comment: Are you running 64-bit mode?

Comment: Show us your code

Comment: This is probably a code problem, not a memory system problem. Even a 32-bit Linux system should support a 4GB virtual memory space.

Comment: Check if malloc is returning NULL if it fails to alloc. You might be memsetting null pointer which might be resulting in SIGSEGV

Comment: @Barmar I think so, and I did not add any compiler option such like -m32 or -m64

Comment: @David Even if you have 4GB virtual memory, you may not have 1GB contiguous space available.

Comment: What is the return value of `malloc`? Is it NULL?

Comment: @Barmar You don't need 1GB of contiguous space available, that's the whole point of modern memory paging systems. A 1GB allocation could use as much as 262144 separate pages.

Comment: @David You need 1GB contiguous *virtual* memory.

Comment: `1024^3` is not `1024*1024*1024`.  Post enough code to replicate the problem as you actually encountered.

Comment: Thank you all, I update the question, and I'm sure I get a non-null pointer

Comment: Constraint violation for attempted `void*`-arithmetic.

Comment: @chux Sure, I'll do it

Comment: @EOF True, but gcc allows `void*` arithmetic as an extension, treating `sizeof(void)` as 1.

Comment: `7f7509ce6010-7f7509d66010` are not `65536` apart.  Suggest using `char *based `

Comment: @chux: Yea, I just figured that out too. This means the OP's code is at best misleading. Also, 128 MB * 8 is exactly the 1 GB.

Comment: @chux ah..the devil is hidden in my code. But I seem to find a possible reason: size_t is unsigned integer, and another arithmetic is signed integer.

Comment: @EOF yeah I know 128MB * 8 is 1GB, but is there has any relation in my code?

Comment: `7f7509ce6010 - 7f7509d66010` is `0x80000`.  `stage` may have value of 0x80000 in `while (initialized < mem_size)` loop if pointers are linear.

Comment: @KChi you should post the _exact_ code that you're using, as a _complete_ program rather than a snippet. You shouldn't even ask a question without doing so.

Comment: There's also undefined behavior here for passing a `void*` to `printf()` with a `%lx`-conversion specifier.

Comment: @davmac yes it's my bad, thanks for reminding

Comment: I do not trust `based + mem_size` is working as hoped.  Use `char * based`.  Look at `Allocated 1073741824 Bytes from 7f74c9e66010 to 7f76c9e66010`.  The difference of those 2 pointers is `8589934592.0`.

Comment: IIRC, Linux memory allocation can (used to be able to) over-commit — say that the memory is available when you allocate it but come back with "just kidding" when you go to use it (by generating a segmentation fault).  Note that standard C says adding offsets to a `void *` is undefined behaviour; GCC treats it as if `sizeof(void) == sizeof(char)`.  Have you used `ulimit -m` to check the maximum memory your process is allowed to use?  It probably isn't a factor here, but if there's a limit, that could be your problem.

Comment: Is `void *based` really coded as posted or maybe `void **based`?  The output points to a factor of 8 coming from somewhere.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Linux can over-commit and this is usually enabled (it can be disabled), however, you don't get a segmentation fault when trying to access memory that isn't available. The "OOM killer" steps in and chooses a process to kill, which might not even be the same process (though it usually is).

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible issues here. The first is that you're not using `malloc()` correctly. You need to check if it returns `NULL`, or a non-`NULL` value.

The other issue could be that the OS is over-committing memory, and the out-of-memory (OOM) killer is terminating your process. [You can disable over-committing of memory and getting dumps to detect via these instructions.](https://serverfault.com/questions/662201/get-a-core-dump-of-debugging-a-process-killed-by-oom-killer)

## Edit

Two major problems:

- Don't do operations with side effects (ie: `n++`) inside a logging statement. VERY BAD practice, as logging calls are often removed at compile time in large projects, and now the program behaves differently.
- Cast `based` to a `(char *)`.

This should help with your problem.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    size_t mem_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    printf("MEMSIZE: %lu\n", mem_size);
    printf("SIZE OF: void*:%lu\n", sizeof(void*));
    printf("SIZE OF: char*:%lu\n", sizeof(char*));
    void *based = malloc(mem_size);  //mem_size = 1024^3
    int stage = 65536;
    int initialized = 0;
    if (based) {
        printf("Allocated %zu Bytes from %p to %p\n", mem_size, based, based + mem_size);
    } else {
        printf("Error in allocation.\n");
        return 1;
    }
    int n = 0;
    while (initialized < mem_size) {  //initialize it in batches
        //printf("%6d %p-%p\n", n, based+initialized, based+initialized+stage);
        n++;
        memset((char *)based + initialized, '$', stage);
        initialized += stage;
    }

    free(based);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I'm sure I got a non-null pointer (I updated the sample code as above), and according to the information from htop, there should be enough available memory in my computer

Comment: @KChi What happens when you run the following: `gcc -O0 -ggdb test.c && gdb -ex run ./a.out`? Does `gdb` from an `error in allocation`? Does the tip I provided on OOMK help?

Answer (score -1):

Holy, I found the problem - pointer type goes wrong.

Here is the complete code

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    /*Allocate 1GB memory*/
    size_t mem_size = 1024 * 1024 * 1024;
    // the problem is here, I used to use pointer as long long type
    char* based = malloc(mem_size);
    // and it misleading system to calculate incorrect offset
    if (based) {
        printf("Allocated %zu Bytes from %lx to %lx\n", mem_size, based, based + mem_size);
    } else {
        printf("Allocation Error.\n");
        return 1;
    }

    /*Initialize the memory in batches*/
    size_t stage = 65536;
    size_t initialized = 0;
    while (initialized < mem_size) {
        memset(based + initialized, '$', stage);
        initialized += stage;
    }

    /*And then I set the breakpoint, check the memory content with gdb*/
    ...
    return 0;
```

Thank you for the people who have given me advice or comments :)

Comment: So, let's be clear: In the question you wrote: `void *based`, but in the real code you actually had `long long *based`, is it right?

Answer (score -2):

It is very unusual for a process to need such a large chunk of continuous memory and yes, the kernel does impose such memory limitations. You should probably know that `malloc()` when dealing with a memory request larger than 128 Kb it calls `mmap()` behind the curtains. You should try to use that directly.

You should also know that the default policy for the kernel when allocating is to allocate more memory than it has. 
The logic is that most allocated memory is not actually used so it relatively safe to allow allocations that exceed the actual memory of the system.

**EDIT:** As some people have it pointed out, when your process does start to use the memory allocated successfully by the kernel it will get killed by the OOM Killer. This code has produced the following output:

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int arc, char**argv)
{
  char *c = malloc(sizeof(char) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5);

  if(c)
  {
    printf("allocated memory\n");
    memset(c, 1, sizeof(char) * 1024 * 1024 * 1024 * 5);  
    free(c);
  }
  else
  {
    printf("Out of memory\n");
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
 $ ./a.out 
    allocated memory
    Killed
```

But after you change the limits of the system:

```
# echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory 
# exit
exit
$ ./a.out 
Out of memory
```

As you can see, the memory allocation was successful on the system and the problem appeared only after the memory was used 
**:EDIT**

There are limits that the kernel imposes on how much memory you can allocate and you can check them out with these commands:

```
grep -e MemTotal -e CommitLimit -e Committed_AS /proc/meminfo
ulimit -a
```

The first command will print the total memory and the second will display the limit that the kernel imposes on allocations (CommitLimit). The limit is based on your system memory and the over-commit ratio defined on your system that you can check with this command `cat /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio`.

The Committed_AS is the memory that is already allocated to the system at the moment. You will notice that this can exceed the Total Memory without causing a crash.

You can change the default behavior of your kernel to never overcommit by writing `echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory` You can check the man pages for more info on this.

I recommend checking the limits on your system and then disabling the default overcommit behavior of the kernel. Then try to see if your system can actually allocated that much memory by checking to see if `malloc()` of `mmap()` fail when allocating.

sources: [LSFMM: Improving the out-of-memory killer](https://lwn.net/Articles/548180/)
and **Mastering Embedded Linux Programming** by **Chris Simmonds**

Comment: "This produces a segmentation fault if all process actually try to use all the memory that was allocated to them by the kernel." - I don't believe that's true. Instead, IIRC, the process is killed as if by the SIGKILL signal and a message is logged by the kernel (normally viewable via `dmesg` command).

Comment: As far as I know, that happens if your system has a memory leak and you have a out of memory situation, this is different.

Comment: "if your system has a memory leak and you have a out of memory situation" is exactly the same situation as a process attempting to access memory which has been allocated with overcommit. It's _not_ different.